# Simultaneous multiple socket port connections in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server, wifi

I want to know what is the best way to connect multiple clients to server using sockets for Android based apps. Basically, I have a server mobile app and multiple clients (unknown number, possibly 200) that need to connect to the server using WiFi/Ad-hoc. Information flow is mostly from the server to the clients as text messages but the clients will also send data to the server.  I'm looking for ideas on :

1. establishing and managing new connections and continuous listening to a new connection
2. network architecture / protocol
3. method to get a list of connected clients and updating when clients are disconnected

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend to use [Netty](http://netty.io) library (it should work on android) because it does this task well and efficiently and has good documentation and sample (there is sample that does almost what you want). It make it simple to implement this client/server architecture in async way without lots of manual low-level work.

But I'm not sure that server with 200 connections running on android is a good idea: even if performance will be enough (on top-level android devices), it is going to be a really battery-drainer. I'd recommend to consider moving all this connection handling to server-side, if it is possible.